# How to get HTML Form multiple values in java sevlet.?

Tags: java, servlets

i have a html form which consists of many fields like contact no, name, email, address and many more, can i get all values of this form in servlet, with a single command or with the help of some method..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using this code.

```
Enumeration en=request.getParameterNames();
String[] values=new String[100];
for(int i=1;en.hasMoreElements();i++)
{
    String param=(String) en.nextElement();
    values[i]=request.getParameter(param);
    [i]=request.getParameter(“param”);
    ps.setString(i,values[i]);           
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

well you can get a map of all the parameters carried from the servlet

like this

```
Map params = request.getParameterMap();
Iterator i = params.keySet().iterator();

while ( i.hasNext() )
  {
    String key = (String) i.next();
    String value = ((String[]) params.get( key ))[ 0 ];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain Akhtar, so nice of You, God Bless You, can i ask u another question that how i can store these values to database, suppose i have made connection to database n all that. But the contact no should be stored in contact column and the address should be in address n rest all respectively.

Comment: @Asad : dude , you dont need to be this much thankful , the community is for helping , so if there is anything to say thanks for , say it to STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: @Asad : as far as your second question is concerned , mention the column names in your insert query in JDBC , I hope you are well aware of JDBC in java , and also use prepared statements .

Comment: Hussain: yup i have made connection with jdbc and aware of prepared statement,  i try that.